# CSS unordered list aligning

Tags: css, html-lists

I've searched around and found a lot of questions about this problem, but none of the answers I tried seemed to work in my case. So I have a unordered list inside of the nav tag and I want the list to be centered relative to the parent nav tag. But the list is always a bit to the right and never in the center no matter what I tried.

HTML pretty straight forward:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>MENU</li>
    <li><a href="">Opt 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Opt 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Opt 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS so far:

```
nav {
float: left;
width:15%;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
background:gray;
text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
color:blue;
}
```

Any ideas how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This totally worked! Thanks so much! Completely forgot about the padding and margin... :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Please make the answer to the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

this is because `ul` have a `padding` and `margin` applied to it by browsers by default you need to remove them

```css
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU</li>
    <li><a href="">Opt 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Opt 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Opt 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
 <nav>
       <ul>
            <li>MENU</li>
            <li><a href="">Opt 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opt 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opt 3</a></li>
      </ul>
 </nav>

nav { 
   display:table;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding : 10px; 
}
```